# Gem for Blog Comments and Star Rating in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

What are the gems for including `Comments` and `Star Rating` in an Rails 3.2.8 App? Also, if there are any articles I can read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you shouldn't use gems for this and do it yourself instead?

- [acts_as_commentable](https://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable) - adds comments to your models
- [lets_rate](https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate) - adds ratings